# Twilio Grant access token and capability token

Tags: android, go, chat, twilio

I am developing a chat app in Android using Twilio. I went through [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/identity) link. If I am not mistaken then; to do chatting, a server must send a token to a client. Once client get's that token then he is ready to initialize Twilio SDK and do chat after that.

My server is written in go-lang, so thought of using my existing login system. Just wondered, how can I grant the access to the token generated by my server? I did not see any REST API for granting the access for that token.

Also when I went through the example given by Twilio, they have used capability token. How a capability token is different from access token?

Comment: You can generate the token on the client or the server, If your server is the only thing connecting to Twilio, then YOU have to auth with Twilio. If your users are required to have their own Twilio account, then you will need to generate the token using their Twilio API key and credentials. The link you posted shows you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Capability tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) sign communications from devices to Twilio and they are typically used with Twilio Client.

Access Tokens should be used to authenticate SDKS for Video and IP Messaging and you can see [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) for the REST API reference.

Comment: not able to find the REST API end point for granting the access. As my server is in Golang, I need to grant the access to my token explicitly using REST API call. Twilio does not have official go sdk hence I am not able to grant the access to my token.

Answer (score 0):

Access Tokens are different from the Capability Tokens used in the previous versions of Twilio Client. Using a Capability Token in the Programmable Voice SDK will not work. Access Tokens, just like Capability Tokens before, are JWT tokens, but are using a new, more flexible format that is used across all the new Twilio SDKs.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk